# Find and string in a string and change it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 2-dimensional array of values looking like that:

[image]

In a different table, I have long strings with VALUE_1, VALUE_2 that can be found anywhere. It looks like in the table below:

[image]

Now, I want to write a program that translates the existing VALUE_1, VALUE_2 etc. in the long strings by adding the respective element in the 2nd dimension of the array (/BB, /CCC etc.) and if necessary duplicating and separating the values with a comma and a blank space. So **VALUE_1** for example is turned into **VALUE_1/BB, VALUE_1/A** for **each** finding in the string. The result is supposed to look exactly like in the table below.

[image]

That's challenging. I my first approach I tried to locate the VALUE_1, VALUE_2 in the strings by using InStr() but I don't think that this will help me since only the first hit is taken into consideration. I need every occurrence.

```
For i = 1 To Worksheets("table2").Range("H1").End(xlDown).Row

    For j = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)

        If InStr(Worksheets("table2").Range("H" & i), arr2(j, 0)) > 0 Then

            Worksheets("table2").Range("H" & i).Font.Bold = True

        End If

    Next j

Next i
```

Comment: It would be much simpler if your left hand column had a list of unique items with the corresponding replacement value in the next column.

Comment: **How did you load the arrays in discussion**? Directly from the range, or by iteration? The array you show looks like a 2D type **with a column**. Is it different? How did you `Dim`, `reDim' it, if the case? In such a case `arr2(j, 0)` has no meaning for VBA. Then, if you have two such arrays, why using ranges value and not comparing the two array, which will be a little faster? Or even better, why not having a single 2D array containing both involves arrays and working only in memory, the range to be marked (bolded font) being placed in a `Union Range` and drop it once, at the end...

Answer (score 2):

Use your 2D table to build a scripting dictionary so that value1 is associated with the concatenation of all column  values in column 2 that have value 1 in the first column.

In the (untested) code below the array (ipArray)is that derived from the 2D range.

```
Public Function GetReplacements(ByVal ipArray As Variant) As Scripting.dictionary

    Dim myD As Scripting.dictionary
    Set myD = New Scripting.dictionary
    
    Dim myIndex As Long
    For myIndex = LBound(ipArray) To UBound(ipArray)
        Dim myKey As String
        myKey = ipArray(myIndex, 1)
        
        Dim myItem As String
        myItem = ipArray(myIndex, 2)
        
        If myD.exists(myKey) Then
        
            myD.Item(myKey) = myD.Item(myKey) & ", " & myKey & myItem
            
            
        Else
        
            myD.Add myKey, myKey & myItem
        
        
        End If
        
    Next
    
    Set GetReplacements = myD

End Function
```

Now when you find an item such as "Value 1" you can replace with the value retrieved from the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @freeflow's excellent answer, I would also use a Scripting.Dictionary to hold the mappings from VALUE1 etc. to the target text.

I would then use Replace for each key in the Dictionary. You can loop like:

```
Dim key as Variant
For Each key in dict
    Replace(<your string>, CStr(key), dict(key))
Next key
```

This will work so long as all your 'find' strings are totally unique i.e. none of them appears within another - so if you had "Value" and "Value 1" it would not work. Also, the simplest form of this method only works if there is a one-to-one mapping of text strings.
Thus, if your sample data is representative, you would want to look into using the Count argument of Replace so that you can replace the second occurrence of VALUE_4 with the different text, and so on.

I would do this by storing the dict values as an array e.g.

```
Dim my_arr(1 to 3) as String
my_arr(1) = "VALUE_4/CCC"
my_arr(2) = "VALUE_4/DDDD"
my_arr(3) = "VALUE_4/A"
dict.Add "VALUE_4", my_arr
```

Then when you are looping through, you can keep track of a counter (call it 'i' for example) and then you can just use Replace with a count of 1, increment 'i' by 1, and then use 'i' in each iteration to call on the relevant element of the array stored against VALUE_4 in the dict, like:

```
For Each key in dict
    For i = LBound(dict(key)) to UBound(dict(key))
        Replace (<your string>, CStr(key), dict(key)(i), 1, 1)
    Next i
Next key
```

Hopefully you can build from there to what you need? Having reread your original post, I actually think my simplest solution would work (but I'll leave the more complex solution there in case it's of use to you or others), so long as dict is used to store the one-to-one mapping of, for example, "VALUE_1" to "VALUE_1/BB, VALUE_1/A" - you can loop through your original table and build those strings by concatenation - maybe even directly in the dict:

```
For Each cell in TableCol1 ' assuming it is cells, otherwise use an appropriate form of loop
    tmp_str = cell.Value2
    If dict.Exists(tmp_str) Then
        dict(tmp_str) = dict(tmp_str) + ", " + tmp_str+cell.Offset(0,1).Value2
    Else
        dict.Add tmp_str, tmp_str + cell.Offset(0,1).Value2
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: naughty naughty, using + when it should be & <big grin>

Comment: Ha true - you can tell I've been doing more Python than VBA lately. For completeness - I believe you only have to use '&' instead of '+' if some of the content could be numeric, is that right? So in the above example, '+' will be fine, but perhaps '&' is better for robustness and wider applicability.

Comment: Be guided by the code inspections of the free and fantastic Rubbberduck addin for VBA.  With VBA its always better to be explicit about what you want rather than assuming that the implicit coercion of datatypes will always yield what you think it will yield.

Comment: Too true! I have even started prefixing some VBA-native functions with 'VBA.' because of intermittent glitches with scoping e.g. the String() function does not always work in all contexts, in my experience, so I end up writing VBA.String() to be safe!